# Attempt to get length of null array Kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Please tell me what could be the problem. there are 2 identical applications (in java and the equivalent in kotlin) with the same permishins

```
<uses-permission android: name = "android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android: name = "android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

these applications have the same Java class

```
public class ShinimaHuynya {

private static ShinimaHuynya instance;

public static ShinimaHuynya getInstance () {
    return instance;
}

ShinimaHuynya () {
    this.instance = this;
}



boolean requestPermission (Activity ac) {
       if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT> = Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
           if (ac.checkSelfPermission (Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)! = PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
               ac.requestPermissions (new String [] {Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 0);
               return false;
           } else {
               return true;
           }
       } else {
           return true;
       }
    }


public void freeAllAppsCache (Handler handler) throws Exception {
    Context context = App.Companion.getInstance (). GetApplicationContext ();
    File externalDir = context.getExternalCacheDir ();
    if (externalDir! = null) {
        PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager ();
        for (ApplicationInfo info: pm.getInstalledApplications (256)) {
            File externalCache = new File (externalDir.getAbsolutePath (). Replace (context.getPackageName (), info.packageName));
            if (externalCache.exists () && externalCache.isDirectory ()) {
                try {
                    deleteFile (externalCache);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace ();
                }
            }
        }
       ...
}

public boolean deleteFile (File file) throws Exception {
    if (file.isDirectory ()) {
        for (String name: file.list ()) {
            if (! deleteFile (new File (file, name))) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return file.delete ();
}
}
```

the class is called the same in java (and equivalent in kotlin)

Java ------

```
if (ShinimaHuynya.getInstance (). requestPermission (this))
        ShinimaHuynya.getInstance (). FreeAllAppsCache (null)
```

kotlin ----

```
if (ShinimaHuynya.getInstance (). requestPermission (this))
        ShinimaHuynya.getInstance (). FreeAllAppsCache (null)
```

at startup, permishins are issued, but the problem is that the deleteFile function in java works fine and in Kotlin it gives an error Attempt to get length of null array

in

```
for (String name: file.list ())
```

what is the problem I can not understand the application equivalents checked on Api 29

Answer (score 0):

Maybe in case you've passed to the Delete function a null file? (you should check in debugger)

try to change the 'if' to:

```
@Throws(Exception::class)
fun deleteFile(file: File): Boolean {
    if (file.exists()) {       // changed if (.exists)
        for (name in file.list()) {
            if (!deleteFile(File(file, name))) {
                return false
            }
        }
    }
    return file.delete()
}
```

(kotlin code)

Comment: The file ment to be a folder? maybe the function in kotlin returns null array if the folder is empty?